# PHP, Changing download filename

Tags: php, csv, http-headers, webclient

I have a PHP code where the user can download a CSV file:

```
header( 'Content-Type: text/csv' );
$file = fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );
//-- Write stuff
fclose($file);
```

Usually, the browser starts to download the content to a file. But it'll save the downloaded file always with the name "csv.csv". Is there a way to change this default name?

For example, in a previous page, I could ask the user which name he/she wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the Content-Disposition header:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.csv"');
```

or

```
header('Content-Disposition: filename="file.csv"');
```

or

```
header('Content-Disposition: filename="' . $filename . '"');
```

Comment: Simple as it should be! Thank you! =)